# "to complete university" vs "to complete a university"

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Is it correct to say

> When he completed a university, he wanted to be an actor

And what's the difference between it and

> When he completed university, he wanted to be an actor

Thanks in advance

Comment: Idiomatically, it's [almost always](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+completed+university%2Che+finished+university&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20finished%20university%3B%2Cc0)  *he **finished** university*, not *he completed university*. The same as, for example, *Finish your dinner!* - an exhortation to eat ***all*** your dinner *(**eat it up**)*, which would never occur as *Complete your dinner!*

Comment: Or perhaps "After graduating ..."

Comment: "When he completed a university" would suggest to me that he had built a university, or painted one, or photographed one, or something like that.

Comment: So, it is not correct to say "When he finished a university" to express gradiation?

Comment: It is incorrect.

Comment: If you're a construction worker, pouring concrete to build a university, then you can complete a university. If you're a good  student, then you can complete university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, saying "When he completed university" is better than the first sentence because you don't know which university he completed. In the second sentence, you still don't know, but it is implied that it doesn't matter. It is still a bad sentence though.

The problem with saying you completed university is that you can't complete a university. You can graduate from a university and get a degree. You can even get a doctorate degree, which is the highest degree they offer, but to complete something means you have done everything they have to offer, and no human can do that.

Comment: Not entirely true: completed: to bring to an end; finish: Has he completed his new novel yet? From dictionary.com

Comment: Yet "when he finished university" is acceptable in BrE, as @FumbleFingers pointed out.  So, while "he completed university" might not quite be idiomatic, I think it's over-rationalising to say that there are good reasons for that (such as the phrase not indicating which university he completed or somehow suggesting that he completed every single course).